# How am I supposed to mock my class if I have beans injectated both by Lombok RequiredArgsConstructor and @Autowired?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

So I have this class (used lombok):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {
    private final BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private TableService tableService;

    public void method() {
        if (!bookService.isEmpty()) return;

        Object table = tableService.getObject();
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {
    @Mock BookService bookService;
    @Mock TableService tableService;

    @InjectMocks ServiceImpl serviceImpl;


    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        when(bookService.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
        when(tableService.isEmpty()).thenReturn(new Object());

        serviceImpl.method();
    }
}
```

If I run it, the `bookService` is null. It is not injected in the class. When the code is at the  `if (!bookService.isEmpty()) return;` the `bookService` is null.

if I change my `testMethod` to this:

```
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(bookService.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
        when(tableService.isEmpty()).thenReturn(new Object());

        serviceImpl.method();
    }
```

So I added `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` then the code `Object table = tableService.getObject();` in my class returns null. So the `tableService` is not null, but the `getObject()` return null;

Any idea how to fix it? I am not let to change the class code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Any idea how to fix it?* - Do not use field injection, use constructor injection instead. --- "*I am not let to change the class code.*" - In that case, one would have to go with manual reflection, which I highly discourage. It would be much simpler to switch from field- to constructor injection.

Comment: Yeah... I would like to... But the company asked my company to make code coverage does not want us to change the code...

Comment: In that case, I would talk to the product owner, explain the situation and stress that the "fix" (for this particular case) would take 10 minutes, whereas the workaround (reflective access) would take about half a day and is not easy to understand and maintain. If the product owner still wants to proceed with the reflective way, then do it. I would also stress that "*writing tests for the sole purpose of coverage*" is pretty pointless and that some adjustments to increase testability should be allowed.